# Docker client not working under ubuntu 12.04.4

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Followed the instructions of installing docker (0.0.9) under ubuntu server 12.04 but every time I run any docker subcommands I got:

```
read unix /var/run/docker.sock: connection reset by peer
```

it happens with docker ps, docker info, etc,
running:

```
service docker status
```

reports that docker daemon is running, I have defaults everywhere on a clean 12.04 server installation without firewall. Can you please advice where to look?

Comment: Heya, another question: did you get the 'connection reset' straight away, or did the docker client sit there and wait for a long time first?

Comment: if you can send us some logs it might be interesting to look into.

Comment: Docker client keeps running for a minute or so and then it raises connection reset by peer: here is the log https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4743#issuecomment-38055106

Answer (score 0):

what do you get when you run

```
ps aux | grep docker
```

is the Docker daemon in there?

Comment: yes it is, still don't know the cause but removing /var/lib/docker did the trick! yiaks :-(

Comment: it could have been too many containers and images - the daemon needs to load all the information before it talks to you.

Comment: I just had one image, shipyard's one.